# How i get image from database to view file in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

```
 <img  src="{{$post->image}}"  width="140" height="140">
```

this is the line which i use to get image from database to view file

i use bellow controller to get this image

```
public function show($id)
{

    $post=Clients::find($id);
    return view('pet.shw',['post'=>$post,'pets'=>$post->pets]); }
```

and also migration file is shown bellow

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('ename');
        $table->string('mobile');
        $table->string('mail');
        $table->binary('image') ; //image that i wanna use 
        $table->mediumText('Discription');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

this approach was not worked [view shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh4R0.png)
how can i solve this problem,suggest the new approaches better than that, i can't use public/storage folder because of all the images should be saved in database

Comment: can you post `$post->image` example value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$img = base64_encode($post->image);

<img src="data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64,<?php echo $img ?>"/>
```

Or you can just replace the image line with the following

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64,{{base64_encode($post->image)}}"/>
```

To dynamically set the mime type make a helper function and use it

```
function constructImageFromBinary($file, $mime) 
{  
  $contents = file_get_contents($file);
  $base64   = base64_encode($contents); 
  return ('data:' . $mime . ';charset=utf8;base64,' . $base64);
}
```

and use the help function in blade template as shown below

```
<img src="@php echo constructImageFromBinary($post->image,'image/png'); @endphp"/>
```

Comment: be careful using `data:image/jpg` this is assuming all uploaded image have mime type of  `image/jpg`